# How do I undo cheating to unlock MissingNo?

Tags: vampire-survivors

I unlocked MissingNo in an earlier version of Vampire Surviors by [editing my save file](https://screenrant.com/vampire-survivors-how-to-unlock-missingno-guide/). Recently the game added [a legitimate way of unlocking MissingNo](https://primagames.com/tips/how-to-unlock-missingno-secret-character-legitimately-without-file-editing-in-vampire-survivors). I want to try unlocking them legitimately, but the new unlock criteria for MissingNo is already marked as cleared in the secrets menu.

Is there a way for me to make MissingNo a locked character again so I can try unlocking them legitimately?